# egit pull dialog "when pulling" options

Tags: eclipse, egit

I have recently moved an   ecliplse project  from svn to git. I have basic understanding of what push and pull is  Could someone be so kind to explain what are 4 different choices for "when pulling" option in the eclipse pull dialog [image: Eclipse->Team->Pull->When pulling] in terms off eclipse (what would happen if I select each one of them)/ Cant seem to find this info anywhere not even in the egit wiki tutorial

Comment: In Git you pull commits from a branch into your local current checked-out branch. With the first two options you tell from which branch. The third option is what should happen if you have made commits in your checked-out branch in the meantime: _rebase_ results into a linear history moving your commits to the end of the history, _merge_ will create a merge commit with two parents, your last commit and the last pulled commit. The last option, I guess, is to remember the previous choices.

Comment: Thanks @howlger. I've updated my picture to clarify,I'm particullary interested in what "rebase interactively" and "rebase preserving merge commit" does

Comment: _Rebase preserving merge commits_ is the same as `git rebase -r` in the command line Git and explained [here](https://mtyurt.net/post/2019/git-rebase-merges-option.html). _Rebase interactively_ opens EGit's _Interactive Rebase_ view to rebase manually instead of automatically.

Comment: Keep in mind, in contrast to SVN, in Git a commit is not a new state/revision but only the change/diff to the previous state, so commits can be re-ordered as long as they do not change the same lines or nearby lines (changing lines far apart in the same file is not a merge conflict in Git). Rebasing moves your not yet pushed commits to the end of the history, or more precisely, a rebase deletes your not yet pushed commits and reapplies the commits instead (causing new commits being created instead).